# Php function appearing not declared

Tags: php, android, mysql, authentication, web-hosting

I am trying to make a login android system and when I try to log in I am getting the error `"undefined function consigueResultado"` at line 74 but I declared the function. Does anybody know what could be wrong? 
I am using 000webhost could that have anything to do with this error? Thanks :)

```
 <?php
class DB_Functions {

    private $conn;

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $db = new Db_Connect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }

    public function consigueResultado( $stmt ) {
        $RESULT = array();
        $stmt->store_result();
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $stmt->num_rows; $i++ ) {
            $Metadata = $stmt->result_metadata();
            $PARAMS = array();
            while ( $Field = $Metadata->fetch_field() ) {
                $PARAMS[] = &$RESULT[ $i ][ $Field->name ];
            }
            call_user_func_array( array( $stmt, 'bind_result' ), $PARAMS );
            $stmt->fetch();
        }
        return $RESULT;
    }

    /**
     * Storing new user
     * returns user details
     */
    public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
        $uuid = uniqid('', true);
        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
        $stmt->bindParam("sssss", $uuid, $name, $email, $encrypted_password, $salt);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $user = consigueResultado( $stmt );
            $stmt->close();

            return $user;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get user by email and password
     */
    public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email =:email");

        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $user = consigueResultado( $stmt );
            $stmt->close();
            return $user;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check user is existed or not
     */
    public function isUserExisted($email) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT email from users WHERE email = :email");

        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            // user existed 
            $stmt->close();
            return true;
        } else {
            // user not existed
            $stmt->close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Encrypting password
     * @param password
     * returns salt and encrypted password
     */
    public function hashSSHA($password) {

        $salt = sha1(rand());
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
        $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
        return $hash;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypting password
     * @param salt, password
     * returns hash string
     */
    public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

        $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

        return $hash;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You define the function inside your class. That means you have to access it using a class object, for example like that: `$this->consigueResultado(...)`

Comment: Yep. Exactly as arkascha said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions in classes are called methods. Methods don't exist in your global scope, but in your object's scope. Read through [Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) to understand this better. The direct impact of this is you shouldn't attempt to call the *function* consigueResultado, but instead the method like this:

```
$user = $this->consigueResultado( $stmt );
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside class we have to use $this key word for call a method of current class,for example your method call should be like this

```
$this->consigueResultado( $stmt );
```

Answer (score 2):

Please Create a object for the class after that you can invoke the function.

```
 $obj = new Yourclassname();
 $obj->yourfunction();
```

Like this...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to call the function using `self`. Try this `self::consigueResultado(..);`.

Answer (score 0):

Why have you used ":email" instead of "s"?

Where is that ":email" declared?